# What UTF-8 characters are valid/invalid in utf8 inputenc?

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

I'm writing a Python program that reads some text files and writes the data to some TeX files. Unfortunately the TeX compilation stops with

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:´é« not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

and also with other characters.

Is there a list or an algorithm that tells me which UTF-8 characters I have to filter out?

Comment: You can add characters with the `newunicodechar` package. However, `é` *is* known to `inputenc`. The error (which is about `´é`) suggests an erroneous input to me...

Comment: All are legal, but not all are predefined. What UTF-8 combination you should define is unclear from the error message, because the apostrophe `´` (`0xB2`) is not a valid UTF-8 prefix; can you look the output from a UTF-8 enabled terminal?

Comment: I don't know in advance which UTF-8 characters will appear in my generated file. I'm planning to filter out all chars unknown to LaTeX with the python script, before generating the TeX file. Therefore I would like to know which characters are defined in LaTeX.

Comment: The defined characters depends on your input: by default inputenc loads `ot1enc.dfu`, `t1enc.dfu`, `omsenc.dfu` and `XXenc.dfu` for all font encodings `XX` you are loading with `fontenc`. The log-file gives you a list: `defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)`. But this information won't help you if your input is no valid utf8 as your error message suggests.

Comment: You know which fonts and font encodings you are including in the document so you can arrange that all those encodings have utf8 definitions, so should never get that error. If you are supporting arbitrary unicode input such as hieroglyphics or box symbols or arabic or math operators.. then setting up the fonts is tricky and you would probably be better to use xelatex or lualatex (when decoding utf-8 is automatic)

Comment: Less non-Latin things can also be problematic. For example, `\^w` will do OK with OT1/T1 but `ŵ` is not known to `inputenc` :(. Similarly for `ŷ Ŷ Ŵ` :(. [These characters are not, of course, in the OT1/T1 encodings. They can, however, be composed from characters in those encodings which is why `\^y` will do OK.]